# How to create a stopwatch with at least 98% accuracy and which shows 1/100th of second as well?

Tags: java, android, time

I think that this type of question has already been asked but I could not related to any of those questions. I created a stopwatch
and it incremented every  1/100th seconds but that was far from accurate it was not even 60% accurate , I used `hanlder.post` and `handler.post(...., 10)`.

Comment: Without seeing what you have done (your code), it is really difficult for the community to help. Edit your post to include the code, and since you make reference to accuracy - you may need to explain how you measured this accuracy.

Comment: Sorry for that but i cant share the code right now and for accuracy , i started my stopwatch and an another stopwatch subsequently and found out the tremendous difference between the two times after a few secs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html). If you using `handler.postDelay` the problem is the next catch up will be delay few millisecond. It will be a big problem when you running like 1000 second.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(); //init the timer
Handler handler = new Handler();
int counter = 0; //counter to indicate the total second whenever timer fire

timerTask task = new timerTask();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,500,1000); //(which task to run,forget the usage try google, looping must be milisecond eg.1000 = 1 second)



private class timerTask extends TimerTask{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                counter++;
                if(counter >= 100){ 
                    //do something
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You could take a look with [alarm manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) as well. But I didn't know wether it is helpful for you or not.

Comment: Sorry but i am a newbie to android dev . whats 500 here

Comment: Oh.. Because I develop video looping app that why I need it. It basically call the timer after delay 500 millisecond. Don't get confuse it just delay once the timer increment will not be affect.

Comment: Yes i understand that very well . i was just curious about that and thanks a lot for your help. Really appreciated .

Comment: It boring evening. Could you accept the answer? It not harm you get rep as well.

Comment: Oops sorry ,didn't know accepting answers (using stackoverflow for the very first time and in utter haste)

Comment: Thanks . your code worked like charm